# Getting JQuery UI's datepicker widget as a EmberJS Mixin to work

Tags: jquery-ui, ember.js

In this JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/maxl/mCXND/

(copied and modified from http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/XMgwV/)

I try to create an Ember DatePicker based on JQuery's.

The first problem I run into is this line :

```
var ui = jQuery.ui[this.get('uiType')](options, this.get('element'));
```

jQuery.ui[this.get('uiType')] doesn't return a function, so I suppose that the solution
that I started with works for some jQueryUI widgets, but not all.
I would like a solution that will work for all JQuery-UI widgets,
and in particular JQueryUI's Datepicker.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the jqueryui code, you see that some of them are invoked as a function, others not. You can solve it using this:

```
var ui;
if (typeof jQuery.ui[this.get('uiType')] === 'function') {
   ui = jQuery.ui[this.get('uiType')](options, this.get('element'));
} else {
   ui = this.$()[this.get('uiType')](options);
}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/PzsrT/7/

Comment: FYI this.$() is a shortcut for $(this.get('element'))

Answer (score 2):

One more thing about jQuery UI's datepicker widget as a EmberJS Mixin.
If you want to supply a callback function to handle the beforeShowDay event, you will raise this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

even if your callback function (in your ember view) return an array, like it's specified in the jqueryui doc

```
  beforeShowDay: function(date){
    some code...
    return [true, ''];
  };
```

This happens because nothing is returned after the callback.call in the _gatherEvents function

```
  _gatherEvents: function(options) {
    var uiEvents = this.get('uiEvents') || [], self = this;

    uiEvents.forEach(function(event) {
      var callback = self[event];

      if (callback) {
        // You can register a handler for a jQuery UI event by passing
        // it in along with the creation options. Update the options hash
        // to include any event callbacks.
        options[event] = function(event, ui) { callback.call(self, event, ui); };
      }
    });
  }
```

I fix this by adding a return statement before the callback.call.

```
_gatherEvents: function(options) {
    var uiEvents = this.get('uiEvents') || [], self = this;

    uiEvents.forEach(function(event) {
      var callback = self[event];

      if (callback) {
        // You can register a handler for a jQuery UI event by passing
        // it in along with the creation options. Update the options hash
        // to include any event callbacks.
        options[event] = function(event, ui) { return callback.call(self, event, ui); };
      }
    });
  }
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/thibault/qf3Yu/